# Efficiently navigating out of enclosed curly braces from insert mode in Vim

Tags: vim

Example:

```
int function() {
    //assume cursor is on this line, or any lines within the function's bounds
    //code
    //more code
} //I want to move my cursor here, or the line below
//Ultimately I want to be in insert mode here
```

Currently, what I am doing is exiting out of insert mode with `jj` (mapped to Esc) and then navigating to the closing curly brace using `]}`. Then, with my cursor on the curly brace, I type `a` and then `<CR>`
 so that I get to be in insert mode below the function block and resume typing code for something else. Is there any more efficient way of doing this? I thought about `<C-o>` followed by `]}` but this places my cursor right before the curly brace instead of after... Maybe the best way to address this kind of problem then is to map something like `<C-e>` to `<C-o>]}<Right>`? Surely there is something more simple than this? I feel like this one common situation is really slowing down my vim coding flow, and would love to see how others approach this kind of circumstance in vim! Sorry if this comes out to be such a simple question, but I have tried searching for a solution to no avail. Any ideas? Thank you very much.

EDIT:
I am also wondering how I could implement this in a way that I get to be in insert mode directly below the enclosing bracket surrounding where my cursor is placed (see below example). Currently, if my cursor is on this bracket and I am in normal mode, if I hit `o`, this condition is satisfied. Similarly, if I am in insert mode and my cursor is to the right of the brace, and I hit enter, this condition is satisfied. But is there a fast way of doing this while in insert mode where my cursor is not placed on the brace? For example, is there a way of mapping `<C-e>` to `<C-o>]}o`? This mixes up normal mode and insert mode maps so I am confused by how to do so.

Another example:

Example:

```
int function() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
        //code
        //cursor is here
    } //I want to move my cursor here, or the line below
    //I want to move my cursor here, right below the closing brace, and be in insert mode
} //more code
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
]}o
```

moves to the closing brace and opens a new line below it.

That's ***three*** keys to press, other than mapping it to a shorter key sequence, I fail to see how one would do it more efficiently.

--- edit ---

You can use this insert mode mapping to do the same thing from insert mode:

```
inoremap <C-e> <C-o>]}<C-o>o
```

But I obviously recommend to stay out of insert mode as long as possible.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely most efficient. But is there a way of mapping a key like `<C-e>` to this such that this action can be performed while in insert mode? I am still relatively new to vim and am sort of confused about how a mapping would work in this case.

Comment: This works great, thanks. I know one of the keys to efficient vim usage is staying out of insert mode as much as possible, but if we are writing new code with auto-completing brackets, would this not be an ideal mapping to use? For example, if I write a simple function, I type '{', which inserts a '}' right after my cursor. I then hit enter and type up my function implementation. When I am done with this, I can continue below the function using something like the above mapping, which seems to be ideal. To me this is a huge timesaver, but I am new to vim. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I've used autoclosing for almost a decade until I decided it creates more trouble than it solves and removed that feature from my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Following is  a bit shorter `<C-o>`

- followed by `/}/e+1` moves to the end of the match + 1 column
- or `/}/+1` moves to the match + 1 row

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty nifty! What about cases where I want my cursor to be right below the enclosing curly braces though, like in nested for loops in c? Trying the above out seems to only place the cursor at the very beginning of the line following the enclosing curly brace, and not necessarily directly below it. That would be great!

Comment: @Leeren - removing the *e* takes you to the next line.

Comment: I edited my post to give out a second example. How would you go about moving around in that case? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What I'd usually do in this case (any in many other cases), is to just keep pressing <kbd>}</kbd> until I arrive at the right line. Sure you can use search or `]` or other tools, but if it's just one or two paragraphs above, pressing `}` will be faster.